# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php error while sending huge amount of array data in Laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am sending a huge amount of array data through ajax using Laravel. 
But every time it's giving me `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php` error.
Below is the AJAX code
**AJAX Code**

```
function getDataSet(data){
         $.ajax({
            url: base_url+'/get-data-set',
            data:{'data':data},      
            type:"POST",
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },              
         });        
    }
```

**Route:**

```
Route::post('get-data-set',function(){ /* Do something*/ exit; });
```

**Error Description**

```
    in RouteCollection.php line 207
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 194
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 142
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 729
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 652
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Comment: What is `base_url` and show when do you call `getDataSet()`

Answer (score 1):

You may use incorrect route post request. To easy maintenance in your route should following

`Route::post('/get-data-set',function(){ /* Do something*/ })->name('post.data');`

And ajax code should

```
function getDataSet(data){
     $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('post.data') }}",
        data:{'data':data},      
        type:"POST",
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },              
     });        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot csrf token on your post request.

```
function getDataSet(data){
     $.ajax({
        url: base_url+'/get-data-set',
        data:{
            'data':data,
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
        },      
        type:"POST",
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },              
     });        
}
```